# knnmatch opencv debug assertion failed Expression: vector iterator + offset out of range

Tags: opencv, c++11

Whenever I execute the following code in Debug mode:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce-Hamming");
Mat DescriptTrain, DescriptTest;    //descriptor matrices of Train and Test Images respectively
std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> > dmatches; 
matcher->knnMatch(DescTrain, DescTest, dmatches, true);
```

I get the following error at knnMatch Function:
     "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector iterator + offset out of range"

Can anyone help on what went wrong?

Comment: Are both **Mat DescriptTrain, DescriptTest;** empty?

Comment: No, both have data and have equal dimensions.